# Cannot resolve oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to do a dummy test with jsp/Oracle using ojdbc6.jar, the code as follows (Test.jsp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="oracle.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<html>
<head>

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    Connection con = null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:oracledb",
            "user", "password");        
    con.close();
%>

</body>
</html>
```

When i execute it over Apache Tomcat server, I get this error:

```
Jan 08, 2017 12:31:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [jsp] en el contexto con ruta [/Gest1] lanzó la excepción [No se puede compilar la clase para JSP: 

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [16] en el fichero java generado: [C:\Proyecto\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M15-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M15\work\Catalina\localhost\Gest1\org\apache\jsp\Test_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver resolves to a package

Stacktrace:] con causa raíz
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP: 

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [16] en el fichero java generado: [C:\Proyecto\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M15-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M15\work\Catalina\localhost\Gest1\org\apache\jsp\Test_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
```

I am not sure whether my classpath is configured correctly or not, I think it is because it seems the another sniplet import Oracle.sql worked.

Comment: Avoid using java codes inside JSP page.

Comment: Put the odbc jar in tomcat lib as well and try then.

Comment: Hi. It works just for a while, it seems that each time tomcat server is restarted, the ojdbc6.jar I moved to lib directory is removed from this directory.

Comment: Unrelated, but: never put Java code like that into a JSP page. And never use `DriverManager` to get a connection in a web application. Use a proper DataSource instead (and `Class.forName()` has not been necessary for ages)

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`    ------>incorrect

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

use the second one. 
i hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

```
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

you have missed driver

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are importing `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.*`
You have already imported java.sql.*. 
And also provided `class.forName('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver').` 
So remove the lines

```
<%@page import="oracle.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" %>
```

And be sure you have added ojdbc6.jar in tomat lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> ojdbc6.jar

and then Apply. Thanks everyone!.